# Jinja2 highlight

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have installed jinja highlight in a small flask app. The [highlighting](https://github.com/tlatsas/jinja2-highlight/blob/master/examples/flask/templates/index.html) works great when used directly in templates, but when I call it from the database and try to apply it on an entry, it does not render - it gives me the raw output from the db.

The code from the example:

```
{% highlight 'python' %}    
from fridge import Beer    
glass = Beer(lt=500)    
glass.drink()    
{% endhighlight %}
```

works in the template, but when I try to write and save an entry with the same content, the output is exactly the same, no formatting. I have tried {{ entry }}, {{entry|safe }} and the result is the same.

What am I doing wrong? While this is a particular jinja2 extension, I suppose the problem is more general.

Comment: Can you include the code you're using to call the function, as well as sample input, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: The code is above. Maybe I didn't explain well the problem. When I put the aforementioned code directly in template.html (hardcoded), it gets rendered fine, with all the styles and without the {% highlight %} tags. However, when I write the code above to an entry in the database and then try to render it by calling it in the template - it remains raw. My guess is that I am missing the rendering moment: when the content gets pulled from the DB the template has already been rendered or something like that.

Comment: Are you saying you're including jinja tags in your database? You'll want to either leave that code in your template or call the function and store the output in the database to render into your template later. i.e. the latter option would consist of rendering that snippet into a text field in your database and then dropping it into your template as `{{ entry|safe }}`. It's probably best to leave it in the template as you have it unless there's a compelling reason to move it away from that layer of the code.

Comment: "However, when I write the code above to an entry in the database and then try to render it by calling it in the template - it remains raw"..Can you show this code ?